# Re-tapping M3 to 6-32 UNC

Tags: taps

I have an issue with a project. I have some 6-32 UNC screws that I need to use. I won't get too far into specifics but this is standardized and I cannot use any other screw. The problem I am having is that I found a specialized nut that I need than only comes in metric. Unfortunately it only comes in M3 and M4, not M3.5 which is a close equivalent to 6-32. Although, after looking into it more, I think the thread pitch between 6-32 UNC and M3.5 is different anyhow. Since M3 is a little smaller, would it be possible to get M3 nuts and use a 6-32 UNC tap on it?

Comment: IMHO Retapping a thread close to the one you have will be a mess. Try to find blank nuts to tap. Maybe the manufacturer can send you some untapped ones?

Comment: I've already messaged a few about tapping the thread I need but it will be a while until I hear back so the retap idea is a backup. But that's a good idea to send an untapped if they can't tap the correct one. I already mistakenly bought M3 nuts so I think I might find someone that has a tap just to see what happens. I don't want to buy my own tap if it's not what I need.

Comment: Are you kidding? Taps are cheap, especially the little ones.  You're probably talking under $10 including the T-handle.

Comment: Yeah, I know but why spend $10 on something that _might_ work if I can find out for certain first? If it works then I'll buy one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First, check McMaster-Carr.**  If anyone will stock a specialty nut, it will be them.  (you might also take a swing by Fastenal, but I find them odd to do business with.)

With a tapped hole, the diameter of the hole has a minor and major diameter due to the threads.   The major diameter of a hole tapped M3 [will be](http://mdmetric.com/tech/M-thead%20600.htm) 2.980 millimeters or 0.117 inches, possibly a smidge smaller.

Once you cut a #6-32 thread into a hole, its [minor diameter](http://www.engineersedge.com/thread_strength/internal_screw_threads_chart.htm) is .114" and its major diameter is .138".

Sounds like it will be fine, assuming your application isn't very high strength.  You might want to run the nut through with a drill bit first, such as a #36, .1065", the one recommended for a 6-32 tap.

Comment: I think I may have already checked McMaster-Carr but since I can't recall I'll check again. Good point about trying the drill first.

Comment: Redrilling and tapping worked beautifully. Turns out I did have a 6-32 tap lying around already too. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The tap drill for a m3 is 2.5mm or .0984" the tap for a #6 is .1065" these are fairly close in size but the #6 is larger so there would be some thread depending on the strength needed there may be enough to do the project it would be worth a try since the fasteners are "custom". I would give taping a try to see if there will be enough thread to do the job I don't have any metric taps to measure the depth of the thread for a m3.